# I want to delete multiple selected row from table, but it deletes last rows only

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a two page application. 1st page takes input for creating a table and based on this inputs, a table is created on next page.

This is my first page:

[image]

This is my second page, which is created with first page inputs.
[image]

I want to delete the rows based on the selected check boxes, but it always delete the rows from last.

This is my controllers.js

```
$scope.tableSelection = {};
    ['Delete', function ($itemScope) {
//$rootscope.rows contains the number of rows given as input
                               for (var i = $rootScope.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                          if ($scope.tableSelection[i]) {
                                            //delete row from data
                                              $rootScope.rows.splice(i, 1);
                                            //delete rowSelection property
                                            delete $scope.tableSelection[i];
                                }
                                     }
                                     }]
```

This is my second html page, where i need to delete the rows based upon selection

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" ng-class="{'success' : tableSelection[$index]}">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tableSelection[$index]">
       </td>
           <td  ng-repeat="col in output_columns track by $index">
         &lt;enter data&gt;
       </td>
       <td ng-repeat="col in input_columns track by $index">
         &lt;enter data&gt;
       </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

But Only rows from last are getting deleted and not the one selected.
Can anyone please suggest what I am missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are providing an index value of -1. Splice will always remove the last row if the index value you pass is -1.

Comment: In future, please avoid 'txt' speak. The post limit here is ~30,000 chars, so there is no need to save characters.